# How to use Json parser/generator for objective-c

Tags: objective-c, json

Does anyone have a tutorial of how to use this [Json framework](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/index.html).  It basically allows parsing and generating of json but I have no idea how to use it!

I need to build up a Json request send it to the webservice and then parse the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the followings :

1. [Tutorial: JSON Over HTTP On The iPhone](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)
2. [JSON Framework for iPhone](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/json-framework-for-iphone.html). Don't forget to check [part 2](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html).

Seems that in order to create a JSON string from Obj-C object, you need to use [SBJsonWriter](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/interfaceSBJsonWriter.html) class. Though I have not tested it myself.

Comment: Hi there once again thanks for your help unfortunately I need to know how to build jSon requests in Objective C - these examples assume you are just downloading and parsing the data

Comment: I just added the source in the project.

Comment: sorry i misinterpreted ur comment. let me check if i can provide u a sample to build request. i used it for parsing only :-(